# Is this code suspicious or malicious in any way?

Tags: roblox

This is an extremely long piece of code popularly associated with free model scripts that people commonly add to their game but it always gets deleted by moderators on-site

```
local d=string.byte;local r=string.char;local c=string.sub;local b=table.concat;local s=math.ldexp;local Y=getfenv or function()return _ENV end;local l=setmetatable;local h=select;local f=unpack;local u=tonumber;local function g(d)local e,o,a="","",{}local n=256;local t={}for l=0,n-1 do t[l]=r(l)end;local l=1;local function i()local e=u(c(d,l,l),36)l=l+1;local o=u(c(d,l,l+e-1),36)l=l+e;return o end;e=r(i())a[1]=e;while l<#d do local l=i()if t[l]then o=t[l]else o=e..c(e,1,1)end;t[n]=e..c(o,1,1)a[#a+1],e,n=o,o,n+1 end;return table.concat(a)end;local a=g('21521627521621927622G22722J22N21V27A21727522Y26I26O25J25O22Z21621A27621Y21X22322627621621827622C1Y26225X1E1Y27522821M2811B21M27522D21M1A21628928B2161Q28F27622D1Y28A1B28421628M27528P276');local n=bit and bit.bxor or function(l,e)local o,n=1,0 while l>0 and e>0 do local c,a=l%2,e%2 if c~=a then n=n+o end l,e,o=(l-c)/2,(e-a)/2,o*2 end if l<e then l=e end while l>0 do local e=l%2 if e>0 then n=n+o end l,o=(l-e)/2,o*2 end return n end local function e(e,l,o)if o then local l=(e/2^(l-1))%2^((o-1)-(l-1)+1);return l-l%1;else local l=2^(l-1);return(e%(l+l)>=l)and 1 or 0;end;end;local l=1;local function o()local o,a,c,e=d(a,l,l+3);o=n(o,42)a=n(a,42)c=n(c,42)e=n(e,42)l=l+4;return(e*16777216)+(c*65536)+(a*256)+o;end;local function t()local e=n(d(a,l,l),42);l=l+1;return e;end;local function g()local l=o();local n=o();local c=1;local o=(e(n,1,20)*(2^32))+l;local l=e(n,21,31);local e=((-1)^e(n,32));if(l==0)then if(o==0)then return e*0;else l=1;c=0;end;elseif(l==2047)then return(o==0)and(e*(1/0))or(e*(0/0));end;return s(e,l-1023)*(c+(o/(2^52)));end;local u=o;local function i(e)local o;if(not e)then e=u();if(e==0)then return'';end;end;o=c(a,l,l+e-1);l=l+e;local e={}for l=1,#o do e[l]=r(n(d(c(o,l,l)),42))end return b(e);end;local l=o;local function u(...)return{...},h('#',...)end local function s()local d={0,0,0,0,0,0};local r={};local l={};local a={d,nil,r,nil,l};local l=o()local c={0,0,0};for o=1,l do local e=t();local l;if(e==3)then l=(t()~=0);elseif(e==1)then l=g();elseif(e==0)then l=i();end;c[o]=l;end;a[2]=c for l=1,o()do r[l-1]=s();end;for a=1,o()do local c=n(o(),127);local o=n(o(),33);local n=e(c,1,2);local l=e(o,1,11);local l={l,e(c,3,11),nil,nil,o};if(n==0)then l[3]=e(c,12,20);l[5]=e(c,21,29);elseif(n==1)then l[3]=e(o,12,33);elseif(n==2)then l[3]=e(o,12,32)-1048575;elseif(n==3)then l[3]=e(o,12,32)-1048575;l[5]=e(c,21,29);end;d[a]=l;end;a[4]=t();return a;end;local function b(l,e,i)local n=l[1];local e=l[2];local o=l[3];local l=l[4];return function(...)local r=n;local c=e;local e=o;local n=l;local l=u local o=1;local t=-1;local u={};local a={...};local d=h('#',...)-1;local l={};local e={};for l=0,d do if(l>=n)then u[l-n]=a[l+1];else e[l]=a[l+1];end;end;local l=d-n+1 local l;local n;while true do l=r[o];n=l[1];if n<=5 then if n<=2 then if n<=0 then e[l[2]]=i[c[l[3]]];elseif n>1 then do return end;else e[l[2]]();t=A;end;elseif n<=3 then e[l[2]]=e[l[3]][c[l[5]]];elseif n>4 then local h;local d;local a;local u;local n;e[l[2]]=i[c[l[3]]];o=o+1;l=r[o];e[l[2]]=c[l[3]];o=o+1;l=r[o];n=l[2];u={};a=0;d=n+l[3]-1;for l=n+1,d do a=a+1;u[a]=e[l];end;h={e[n](f(u,1,d-n))};d=n+l[5]-2;a=0;for l=n,d do a=a+1;e[l]=h[a];end;t=d;o=o+1;l=r[o];e[l[2]]=e[l[3]][c[l[5]]];o=o+1;l=r[o];e[l[2]]();t=n;o=o+1;l=r[o];do return end;else e[l[2]]=c[l[3]];end;elseif n<=8 then if n<=6 then e[l[2]]=i[c[l[3]]];elseif n>7 then e[l[2]]();t=A;else local n=l[2];local c={};local o=0;local a=n+l[3]-1;for l=n+1,a do o=o+1;c[o]=e[l];end;local c={e[n](f(c,1,a-n))};local l=n+l[5]-2;o=0;for l=n,l do o=o+1;e[l]=c[o];end;t=l;end;elseif n<=10 then if n==9 then do return end;else e[l[2]]=e[l[3]][c[l[5]]];end;elseif n==11 then e[l[2]]=c[l[3]];else local n=l[2];local c={};local o=0;local a=n+l[3]-1;for l=n+1,a do o=o+1;c[o]=e[l];end;local c={e[n](f(c,1,a-n))};local l=n+l[5]-2;o=0;for l=n,l do o=o+1;e[l]=c[o];end;t=l;end;o=o+1;end;end;end;return b(s(),{},Y())();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's incredibly suspicious. It has been obfuscated, minified, and constructs a complex and unreadable string of byte code to execute. If you can't immediately read and understand code in Free Models, you should expect it's malicious.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I did think this was too suspicious to be this unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This will explain itself.

```lua
local a=g('21521627521621927622G22722J22N21V27A21727522Y26I26O25J25O22Z21621A27621Y21X22322627621621827622C1Y26225X1E1Y27522821M2811B21M27522D21M1A21628928B2161Q28F27622D1Y28A1B28421628M27528P276')
-- doesn't look too good, this is definitely suspicious
local d={0,0,0,0,0,0} -- why would you need this?
-- This has ben obfuscated and minified. Don't trust it.
```

Answer (score -1):

1000){r=r.substring(0,r.length-1);}return r;}());} var ftDomain = (window==top)?"":(function(){var d=document.referrer,h=(d)?d.match("(?::q/q/)+([qw-]+(q.[qw-]+)+)(q/)?".replace(/q/g,decodeURIComponent("%"+"5C")))[1]:"";return (h&&h!=location.host)?"&ft_ifb=1&ft_domain="+encodeURIComponent(h):"";}()); var ftV_6210087={pID:"6210087",width:"300",height:"250",params:{ftx:window.ftX,fty:window.ftY,ftadz:window.ftZ,ftscw:window.ftContent,ft_custom:window.ftCustom,ft_id:window.ftID||"",ft_idEnabled:window.ftIDEnabled||"",ftOBA:window.ftOBA,ft_domain:((ftDomain||"").match(RegExp("&ft_domain=([^&$]+)","i"))||["",""])[1],ft_ifb:((ftDomain||"").match(RegExp("&ft_ifb=([^&$]+)","i"))||["",""])[1],ft_agentEnv:window.mraid||window.ormma?"1":"0",ft_referrer:encodeURIComponent(window.ft_referrer),gdpr:"0",gdpr_consent:"",us_privacy:"${US_PRIVACY}",cachebuster:window.ftRandom},winVars:{ftClick_6210087:window.ftClick_6210087,ftExpTrack_6210087:window.ftExpTrack_6210087,ft300x250_OOBclickTrack:window.ft300x250_OOBclickTrack},DTimeout:1E3,GTimeout:1E3}, ftPProc=function(d){var c=this;d=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d));var f=[],l=function(a,b){b="undefined"===typeof b||isNaN(b)?1:parseInt(b,10);a=a||"";for(var e=0<=b?b:0;e--;)a=encodeURIComponent(a);return a},h=function(a){a=a.constructor==Array?a:[];for(var b=0;b

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).